# Exibir uma Mensagem Direto na página MainPage

Tags: c#

Como exibir uma mensagem direto da MainPage, estou usando MessageDialog, conforme código abaixo:

```
namespace App4
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            var saida = new MessageDialog("Exibir Mensagem");
            //Debug.WriteLine(saida);
            await saida.ShowAsync();

            this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
        }
```

O erro e nesta linha:

```
         await saida.ShowAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

A `keyword` `await` só pode ser utilizada em métodos que possuem a `keyword` `async`. No entanto, os contrutores não permitem a `keyword` `async`, apenas os métodos.

No seu caso eu recomendo que você utilize o evento `loaded` para executar as suas funcionalidades:

```
namespace App4
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;

            this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
        }

        private async void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       {
           var saida = new MessageDialog("Exibir Mensagem");
          //Debug.WriteLine(saida);
          await saida.ShowAsync();

       }
```

Maiores informações sobre o operador await: [MSDN|await (Referência de C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh156528.aspx)